# Why can't I have item span multiple columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm having difficulty spanning box-two to take up column two and three. I've checked for typos. My page looks great before screen width is 1024px. Below is my html page and stylesheet

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 10rem);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 10rem);
  gap: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
  .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10rem);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 10rem);
  }
  .box-two {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="css/images/blackberries.jpg" alt="blackberries">
    </div>
    <div class="box box-two">
      <img src="css/images/brunch.jpg" alt="brunch">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="css/images/utensils.jpg" alt=" cooking utensils">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="css/images/blackberries.jpg" alt="blackberries">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="css/images/brunch.jpg" alt="brunch">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="css/images/utensils.jpg" alt=" cooking utensils">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <img src="css/images/blackberries.jpg" alt="blackberries">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think the issue lies in my stylesheet but I'm having a hard time pinpointing were.

I've tried grid-column: 2 / 4 and other variants of the grid-column command but it simply adds additional columns without letting box-two take up multiple columns. My code isn't bringing up any errors and I've tried seeing if I was missing anything elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think your CSS works as-is, but your image doesn't fill the entire cell when it spans multiple columns so it doesn't appear to be working.

If you run the snippet below (and open it full-screen to get the layout in question) you can see that `box-two` *does* span two columns, but your image is still `width: 10rem` so it doesn't grow.

[image: screenshot of layout]

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 10rem);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 10rem);
    gap: 10px;
}

img {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    visibility: hidden; /* hiding the images for clarity about the grid */
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red; /* so we can see the grid cells */
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    
    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 10rem);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    
    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 10rem);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 10rem);
    }
    
    .box-two {
        grid-column: span 2;
        background: tomato; /* to accentuate this box */
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="css/images/blackberries.jpg" alt="blackberries">
        </div>
        <div class="box box-two">
            <img src="css/images/brunch.jpg" alt="brunch">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="css/images/utensils.jpg" alt=" cooking utensils">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="css/images/blackberries.jpg" alt="blackberries">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="css/images/brunch.jpg" alt="brunch">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="css/images/utensils.jpg" alt=" cooking utensils">
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="css/images/blackberries.jpg" alt="blackberries">
        </div>
    </div>
```

This probably isn't the solution, but just to illustrate: adding this rule will allow the image to scale up and fill the full width:

```
.box-two img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[image: with the width: 100% rule]

Comment: Thanks Ray! While your answer wasn't the complete solution, it did help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try using precise CSS Grid properties (like grid-column-start and grid-column-end) for more control over placement.